# SQL - Reference a column value in the same query context

Tags: sql, select, reference

I need to know if there's any way I can reference a column value in the same query context.

In this example I'm defining "amount" value on the second nested `select` and trying to access it on the first nested `select`.

I'm getting `Reference 'amount' not supported (forward reference in item list)`

I know if I define "amount" first on the columns list it works but it will change the order, affecting target tables.

```
select
    col_1,
    col_2,
    (select if(amount >= 0, 'debit', 'credit')),
    col_3,
    (select json_value((select json from table), '$.key.val')) as amount,
    col_4
from my_table;
```

Is there any way I can assign a value to be available on the query context no matter the order?
I want to avoid duplicating code and make the query more efficient by avoiding redundant calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the json part in a *derived table* (i.e. the subquery):

```
select 
    col_1,
    col_2,
    case when amount >= 0 then 'debit' else 'credit' end,
    col_3,
    amount,
    col_4
from
(
    select
        col_1,
        col_2,
        col_3,
        json_value(_json, '$.key.val') as amount,
        col_4
    from my_table
) dt
```

Comment: I see, then I'd do a JOIN.